# WPF DataGrid doesnt update after instert element to source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I'm new in WPF. I try to do a DataGrid which is binded with my entity framework model table. Name of my table is: Words. Im trying to do simple dictionary.
Im using SQL Sever Compact, WPF, Entity framework.

**However, after removing records from table it is working ok... rows from DataGrid desapers**

Can you tell me why after adding records to entity they are not inseted to DataGrid?
After turn off program and turn on again the records are in DataGrid.

Here is my code of DataGrid window:

```
<Grid>

<Grid>
        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid" DataContext="{Binding }" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,90,0,0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sentence" Binding="{Binding Path=sentence}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Translation" Binding="{Binding Path=translation}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Operations">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding Path=id}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="sentence" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="171,12,131,0" Name="translations" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True" />
        <Button Content="Add" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,41,0,0" Name="addBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="addBtn_Click" />
    </Grid>
```

Here is my c# code:

```
public partial class AddWordWnd : Window {
    static dbEntities db = new dbEntities();

    public AddWordWnd() {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid.DataContext = db.Words;
        dataGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        System.Guid ii = System.Guid.Parse(btn.Tag.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(ii.ToString());
        db.DeleteObject(db.Words.Single(w => w.id == ii));
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void addBtn_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        System.Guid gg = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        db.Words.AddObject(new Words() { id = gg, sentence = translations.Text, translation = sentence.Text });
        db.SaveChanges();
        dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Structure of my database table:

```
Words
---------------
id uniqueidentifier rowguidcol not null primary key,
sentence nvarchar(255) not null,
translation nvarchar(255) not null,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be that the DataContext is getting set to a copy of your item, instead of pointing to the existing item.

Instead of *setting* the DataContext to an item, *bind* it to that item. This will make the DataContext point to the item, instead of copying it.

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = db.Words;
dataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

**Edit**

Just noticed you're binding directly to the context. By default, that doesn't raise the CollectionChanged event to tell your DataGrid that the items have changed, so the DataGrid doesn't try to re-read it's ItemsSource.

Try either refreshing the binding manually (`dataGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget()`), or refreshing the context by requerying the database (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256245/c-entity-framework-data-bound-combobox-does-not-reflect-changes-made-after-sa/3256541#3256541) for an example)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still didnt solve my problem... :/

Comment: Just noticed you're binding directly to the context. By default, that doesn't raise the CollectionChanged event to tell your DataGrid that the items have changed, so the DataGrid doesn't try to re-read it's ItemsSource. Try manually raising the PropertyChanged event on the binding

Comment: That would be greatful if you tell me how can I do this? Im new in WPF. This is my second day when I writting something in WPF.

Comment: @nosbor I believe it is something like `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(dataGrid, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();`

Comment: Yes, I'm reasonably sure that either your DataContext is not pointing directly to your `context.Words` and is working with a copy of the data, or it is simply not raising the PropertyChanged event when a new item gets Added

Comment: Actually since you said your Delete works, its more likely that the PropertyChanged event is not being raised

Comment: So do you have any idea how to fix it? I tried to do somethink like that: dataGrid.Items.Add(word); But a had a exception: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Comment: Well ideally I would never bind directly to the Entity Framework Context. I would load the Items into an `ObservableCollection` at startup, then add/remove items from the collection (in addition to updating your source context)

Comment: My guess is that even though you added the item, the context won't get updated until after you requery the database. See the following link for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256245/c-entity-framework-data-bound-combobox-does-not-reflect-changes-made-after-sa/3256541#3256541