# Refresh data in ListBox after add new one

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, listbox, wpf-controls

Good morning,

I want to refresh data with Binding in listbox after then I add new one.
I'm using MVVM design patter, so my ViewModel has property AllGroups and every group have property TotalCount and Name.
Property AllGroups is ObservableCollection.

In listbox I show name of group and TotalCount.
TotalCount has just getter realized by

```
public int TotalCount
{
  get
  {
    return Items.Count;
  }
}
```

and TotalCount isn't column.

I have group "All" with 2 items (TotalCount=2), but when I add new item to group and show list of groups I see "All" and TotalCount=2 but when I start app again I show "All" and "3".

So, how can I refresh data manually? Thank for help. :)

Comment: Possibly this post will help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455856/wpf-datagrid-doesnt-update-after-instert-element-to-source

Answer (score 2):

You should implement [INotifPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in class that contains `TotalCount`

Once there is any change in `Item` collection raise the property changed event for `TotalCount` property to inform `View` that `TotalCount` has been changed so update View with latest value

Answer (score 1):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, raise the NotifyPropertyChanged event for `TotalCount` when the collection changes, like this:

```
AllGroups.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => OnNotifyPropertyChanged("TotalCount");
```

Comment: What this construction exactly mean? Here is my Group class http://pastebin.com/Rmy4KNEN and Item class http://pastebin.com/2TzJbtNU . INotifyPropertyChanged I have implemented. How can I raise changed event in class Item in reference class Group??

Comment: Neither of those two contains a ObservableCollection, this should be done on the ViewModel.

Comment: Here is my DataContext and ViewModel. http://pastebin.com/s9zp4s8b Property TotalCount is just for help, I can use Groups.Items.Count. Problem is in relations. When I create Item and add it to collection AllItems this new Item has property Group, but this group don't know that exists new item with relation with this group. How can I tell this group: "Hey, exists new item with relation on you. Refresh yourself!" ?? :)

Comment: Okay, so you completely misunderstood MVVM. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Ok, I'll... But can you tell me what I have to focus on?